# Inserting images into pdfmake from Firebase storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, pdfmake

I'm currently using pdfmake in an Angular application on firebase. I'm trying to insert images into a pdf document I'm creating (a table is used and the image is displayed in a row in pdfmake).

```
private afStorage: AngularFireStorage;
```

...

```
{image: this.afStorage.ref("/image.jpg").getDownloadURL(), colSpan: 2, alignment: 'center'}
```

I'm getting the download url of the image from firebase storage but pdfmake gives the following error:

> "invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or
>   local file paths in node.js)"

I have no idea how I can place these images into my pdf document or convert them to dataURL format from firebase storage. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that you're using that doesn't work the way you expect.  Without that, it's impossible to see what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to display image using Image Tag

```
<img id="imageid" src="downloadURL">
```

Then you can get the base64 content.

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

var base64 = getBase64Image(document.getElementById("imageid"));
```

Comment: This can not work for my situation seeing that I'm not displaying the image in html but rather generating a pdf in the background.